# Using apply to the pandas group object with original function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-index df and I want to add a new column by apply an operation

```
class weight  height  time
A       45     150    85
        50     160    80
        55     155    74
B       78     180    90
        51     158    65
        40     155    68
C       80     185    90
        86     175    81
        52     162    73

def operation(col):
    concat = ''
    for i in col:
        concat += (str(i))
    return concat
```

and the result df should look like

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(level=0)['height'].apply(operation)

class weight  height  time new
A       45     150    85   150160155
        50     160    80
        55     155    74
B       78     180    90   180158155
        51     158    65
        40     155    68
C       80     185    90   185175162
        86     175    81
        52     162    73
```

However, the resultant df actually add `NaN` to new column. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

use `transform` instead of `apply`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(level=0)['height'].transform(operation)
```

Output:

```
              height  time        new
class weight                         
A     45         150    85  150160155
      50         160    80  150160155
      55         155    74  150160155
B     78         180    90  180158155
      51         158    65  180158155
      40         155    68  180158155
C     80         185    90  185175162
      86         175    81  185175162
      52         162    73  185175162
```

OR

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(level=0)['height'].transform(operation).drop_duplicates()
```

Output:

```
             height  time        new
class weight                         
A     45         150    85  150160155
      50         160    80        NaN
      55         155    74        NaN
B     78         180    90  180158155
      51         158    65        NaN
      40         155    68        NaN
C     80         185    90  185175162
      86         175    81        NaN
      52         162    73        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Concat height in each class, put it in a dict and map  it back to the column class

  df['new']=df['class'].map(df.groupby('class').height.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.cat()).to_dict())

#Select duplicated(keep=first), invert in np.where clause to null what you need done so

df['new']=np.where(~df['new'].duplicated(keep='first'),df['new'],'')
print(df)



     class  weight  height  time        new
0     A      45     150    85      150160155
1     A      50     160    80           
2     A      55     155    74           
3     B      78     180    90      180158155
4     B      51     158    65           
5     B      40     155    68           
6     C      80     185    90     185175162
7     C      86     175    81           
8     C      52     162    73
```